# Merging yaml files using yaml-merge in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, yaml

From my understanding [yaml-merge](https://pypi.org/project/yaml-merge/#description)  is quite simple. I have two yaml files I want to merge `file1.yml` & `file2.yml`. With that being said the syntax should look something like `yaml-merge file1.yml file2.yml` or `yaml-merge *.yml`.

file1.yml

```
region:
  - name: east
    env: prod
```

file2.yml

```
region:
  - name: west
    env: prod
```

I am expecting an output of

```
region:
  - name: east
    env: prod
  - name: west
    env: prod
```

What I keep getting is a readout of `file1`

```
region:
  - name: east
    env: prod
```

What am I missing here exactly?

My goal is within my ubuntu vm merge all `yml` files in the directory each all similar to `file1` and `file2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project yaml-merge version 0.1.1 seems quite old and unsupported to me.
I suggest to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) for your task instead.

The script shows two versions how you can merge your yaml files.
Version 2 is easier to expand for merging multiple files: Simply create a stream of yaml files and pipe it into `jq`.

The main work is done by `jq`. `yq` is justed used to convert yaml to json on the input side and json to yaml on the output side.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
FILE1='file1.yml'
FILE2='file2.yml'

echo merging yaml files - version 1
jq -n --slurpfile file1 <(yq . $FILE1) \
      --slurpfile file2 <(yq . $FILE2) '
      {region: ($file1[].region + $file2[].region)}' |
yq -y

echo
echo merging yaml files - version 2
echo "$(yq . $FILE1)$(yq . $FILE2)" |
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $input ([];. + $input.region) | {region: .}' | yq -y
```

### `output` merging yaml files - version 1 and 2

```yaml
region:
  - name: east
    env: prod
  - name: west
    env: prod
```

Comment: Thank you, after your response I did look into the jq wrapper yq. I ended up with something slightly different `yq eval-all '. as $item ireduce ({}; . *+ $item )' *.yml`  yielding the same results. Thanks for pointing me in the proper direction.

Comment: This is an interesting compact solution with the other [yq](https://mikefarah.github.io/yq/) (written in Go) instead the [yq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) (written in Python) I am normally using